# CRASHPAD_DB_INIT_ERROR when calling QFileDialog.getSaveFileName in x64 Python

Tags: python, qt

I'm getting this error each time I call any of the `QFileDialog` functions, such as `getOpenFileName` and `getSaveFileName`, no matter if it was launched via Visual Studio Code or just an empty cmd console.

```
[152844:152708:20200401,111013.180:ERROR crash_report_database_win.cc:569] CreateDirectory : The system cannot find the path specified. (3)
Could not initialize crash reporting DB
Can not init crashpad with status: CRASHPAD_DB_INIT_ERROR
```

It seems to only happen on the 64 bit installs, for both 2.7 and 3.7, so it's likely not to be a dodgy `PySide` or `PySide2` install. It's something related to `Crashpad`, but it's not anything we're using in our Python setup, and I'd not even heard of it before today. Searching my C drive comes up with 4 results from various applications, deleting them makes no difference though.

Does anyone have any idea where this might be coming from, and how I could potentially solve/fix it? It doesn't appear to cause any issues other than printing to the console.

Comment: Did you ever find out why you received this error? I'm running into the same thing. It does not seem to be fatal, however I'd still like to know what's going on.

Comment: Sorry no luck haha, it's still happening for me 10 months later.

Comment: I just started getting this on a Python app that calls win32gui.GetOpenFileNameW, no qt involved, just pywin32